# Kiip Ad loads but does not display

Tags: ios, xcode, kiip

- I have integrated Kiip ads into my app.
- When a user accomplishes a task in the app, a Kiip ad successfully
  shows.
- However, a Kiip ad only shows the first time the ad is called for.
- When a user accomplishes a second task, no ad shows, but the ad is
  loaded.

The interesting part of this is that the ad is definitely loading.
My app is storyboard based and I use a cross horizontal modal (the screen flips to show another view controller).
When a user taps a button to modal to a different screen, you can see the kiip ad loaded as the view is flipped (normally the background is simply black when the screen is flipped but there is a kiip ad there instead when the second kiip ad is called on).

Where is the second ad being loaded? 
How do I make the ad load so that users can see the second ad, third ad, etc.?

**EDIT:** After diving into this further, the Kiip ad loads multiple times just fine **IF** I do not modal and modal back to the original View controller.

For example, if I display a kiip ad, modal to a different screen, then modal back, and try to display another kiip ad, the ad does display (but does still load).

```
// Show Kiip Reward and reset task
-(IBAction)resetTasks:(id)sender{

    [[Kiip sharedInstance] saveMoment:@"my_moment_id" withCompletionHandler:^(KPPoptart *poptart, NSError *error) {
        if (error) {
            NSLog(@"something's wrong");
            // handle with an Alert dialog.
        }
        if (poptart) {
            [poptart show];
        }
        if (!poptart) {
            // handle logic when there is no reward to give.
        }
    }];

    //hide the button that allows shows user kiip ad for their accomplishment
    resetButton.hidden = YES;

    //reset other game logic after 4 seconds so there is time for the ad to load
    [self performSelector:@selector(resetGame) withObject:nil afterDelay:4];
}



- (void) kiip:(Kiip *)kiip didReceiveContent:(NSString *)contentId quantity:(int)quantity transactionId:(NSString *)transactionId signature:(NSString *)signature {
    // Give the currency to the user by using your in-app currency management.
    totalCoins = totalCoins + quantity;
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setInteger:totalCoins forKey:@"totalCoins"];
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found a way to get around this if you use modals a lot in your storyboard and the kiip ad won't load.

I added this code to viewDidLoad and the kiip ads now display more than once.

```
-(void) viewDidLoad {
Kiip *kiip = [[Kiip alloc] initWithAppKey:@"YOUR KEY" andSecret:@"YOUR SECRET"];
    kiip.delegate = self;
    [Kiip setSharedInstance:kiip];
}
```